# App crash due to NullPointerException

Tags: android, facebook, nullpointerexception

Trying to integrate facebook sdk to android app.but my application is not starting .unfotunately app stoped  error i showing.from logs i understood it is due to null pointer exception.but didn't find the exact problem .here i am placing the logs.suggest me how to find the error causing line and how to fix this error.Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  String APP_ID = "307128189431829"; // Replace your App ID // here

  // Instance of Facebook Class
  private Facebook facebook;
  Button btnFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  Button postToWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

  @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused" })
  private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
  String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    postToWall.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            postToWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

    btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            loginToFacebook();
            btnFbLogin.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
            postToWall.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    postToWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

tried debugging found that problem in LoginToFacebook method

```
public void loginToFacebook() {
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // Function to handle complete event
                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                        // Function to handle error

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors

                    }

                });
    }
}
```

log details

```
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.sri.z4globalsoft/com.sri.z4globalsoft.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at com.sri.z4globalsoft.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:23)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
08-15 19:13:13.354: E/AndroidRuntime(994):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: You show update error. There are 2 different NPEs!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
String APP_ID = "307128189431829"; // Replace your App ID
                                                    // here

// Instance of Facebook Class
private Facebook facebook;
Button btnFbLogin;
Button postToWall;

@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused" })
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    postToWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    postToWall.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            postToWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
    //Rest is the same
```

Trying to assign your `Button`s a value where you declare them at an instance level, which is before `setContentView()` has been called will result in a null pointer for them.

Comment: Just too fast for me this time ;)

Comment: Make sure that `button1` and `button2` are `id`s in `activity_main.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I can't shake the feeling that this line,

```
postToWall.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        postToWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
```

is the source of your problem. Why not simply write (in addition to the changes already suggested):

```
postToWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

UPDATE:

Unfortunately I don't have access to the Facebook API docs at the moment. Your code in the `loginToFacebook()` method is fairly straightforward. And if it's throwing a NPE in there, it might be related to when you set mPrefs, `mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);`. Failing that, it might also occur when you attempt to get the `SharedPreferences.Editor` object, as that's the only other place you don't check for null. Also, are the logs you have posted pertinent to the errors occuring in `loginToFacebook()`?

Hope this helps!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392147/android-set-visibility-of-a-button-on-timer

Comment: But that answer appears to be related to trying to update the UI from a thread, which is a definite issue. That call postToWall.getHandler() occurs in onCreate, which is executed on the UI thread.

Comment: yes cris you are right ,i tried by debugging the code problem in loginToFacebook() ,i am changing the code .could you please look in to that method and help me.

Comment: Edit your post to include it and I can take a look.