# How to enable a button only on a specific time period in Android?

Tags: java, android, button

I'm working on Android using Java and I have a question.

I want a button to be enabled only during a certain time period. Let's say I want the button to only work between 19:00 and 19:30 and after that it shows a error message, how would I achieve that?

I tried using something like this code, but it didn't work out:

```
public class LocalTimeDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
      LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.parse("12:35:30");
      System.out.println(time1.isBefore(time));  
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use `AlarmManager` and set alarm for specific time!.

Comment: This link help you to visible button through thread start when your  time1 is matched current time. Please see the link and try.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3392175

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the calendar class for this. If you want to do it when activity is resumed then use this code snippet in the onResume method of activity

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int tHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int tmin = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if (tHour = 19 && tmin > 0 && tmin<30){
        btn.setEnabled(true);
    }else{
        btn.setEnabled(false);
    }
```